# SQL LocalDB SELECT statement with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2012, localdb

I created a stored procedure for my .NET project and it goes like this,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_PM_SELECTED]
(
    @acID varchar(50),
    @pmCat varchar(50),
    @pmTitle varchar(50),
    @pmUsername varchar(50),
    @pmSiteURL varchar(100)
)
AS
    SELECT * FROM pmPassword
    WHERE acID  = @acID and
    pmCat like '%' + @pmCat + '%' or
    pmTitle like '%' + @pmTitle + '%' or
    pmUsername like '%' + @pmUsername + '%' or
    pmSiteURL like '%' + @pmSiteURL + '%';
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to select all records that match those fields except that they must be within **acID**. To further explain please take a look below;

```
 acID    pmCat      pmTitle    pmUsername       pmSiteURL  
 1      Windows     Google       MyName     www.somewhere.com     
 2      Network     FTP          MyName     www.somewhere.com
```

Above should look like a table. I only want to show the items with **acID = 1**
Please take note that **acID** does auto increment whenever I add a record which is what I have accomplished in VB alone. **acID is not a PK**. My PK is **pmID** which is not included in the query because I have no use for it. 
I am working with **VB** and **SQL LocalDB** (2012).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` has higher precendence than `OR`. You need to add parentheses to get what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM pmPassword
WHERE acID = @acID
AND
(
    pmCat LIKE '%' + @pmCat + '%' 
    OR pmTitle LIKE '%' + @pmTitle + '%'
    OR pmUsername LIKE '%' + @pmUsername + '%'
    OR pmSiteURL LIKE '%' + @pmSiteURL + '%'
);
```

Your query is interpreted as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM pmPassword
WHERE (acID = @acID AND pmCat LIKE '%' + @pmCat + '%')
OR pmTitle LIKE '%' + @pmTitle + '%'
OR pmUsername LIKE '%' + @pmUsername + '%'
OR pmSiteURL LIKE '%' + @pmSiteURL + '%'
```